# When the kernel says "Out of memory: Killed proces..." does it mean real memory or virtual memory?

Tags: oom

Looking at `journal -xe` for the reason(s) a process is `killed`, the message comes up in red "Out of memory: Killed process..." but it doesn't say whether the limiting resource is virtual memory or is real memory.

Which does it mean and why doesn't it simply say so?

Comment: A nice slightly above entry level write up on the causes of an out of memory error and the OoM killer triggering is this: https://linux-mm.org/OOM  - in short you only get one error because for the kernel the problem is always the same root issue: it can’t free up enough real memory to run all requested tasks. That can coincide with full swap but doesn’t have to be.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer to my two 'and' conjoined questions.

Answer (score 1):

The simply answer is, at the moment your memory usage (RAM) is high and make other proccess cant run.

If your server run on VMs virtualization like KVM etc then it mean virtual memory.

Comment: Virtual memory in this context does not mean a hypervisor and virtual hardware. It means abstracted address spaces that do not necessarily directly map to the contents of DRAM chips.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory